# fedora 29 kernel modules

Tags: module, kernel

The fedora release installed on my system is 4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64. But the kernel src installed on my system is 4.20.3-200.fc29.x86_64.

This is causing problems while installing kernel modules(Invalid module format).

Answer (score 0):

There should be a number of kernel `src` directories in `/lib/modules` as shown below.

My system output:

```
ls /lib/modules/
4.13.0-45-generic  4.15.0-29-generic  4.15.0-32-generic  4.15.0-34-generic  4.15.0-39-generic  4.15.0-43-generic  4.15.0-45-generic
```

**Option 1**: running this command may solve problem. (I use Ubuntu but you can give it try):

```
yum distro-sync
```

**Option 2**: if you are sure about wrong kernel source you can remove it using

```
rm -rf /lib/modules/{BAD_KERNEL_VER} 
rm -f /boot/vmlinuz-{BAD_KERNEL_VER}* 
rm -f /boot/initrd-{BAD_KERNEL_VER}* 
rm -f /boot/config-{BAD_KERNEL_VER}* 
rm -f /boot/System.map-{BAD_KERNEL_VER}*
try installing the kernel source
sudo yum install $(uname -r)
```

Comment: yum-distro install all packages. It doesn't install the kernel-src tree. yum install uname -r doesn't install the source tree.